# ESLint: enforce definition of a React method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

here is a React class:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      {() => this.renderValue('test')}
    )
  }
}
```

Is there anyway that ESLint can throw an error that the class method `renderValue` is not defined in the component?

Comment: Not sure about eslint, but if you wish to use typescript then you can declare such methods in an interface and make your class implement the interface. Typescript will complain if the method is not implemented in the class.

Comment: You should avoid creating functions inside your render method.  Not sure where your val is coming from, but if it is a prop/state or can be handled outside the render function to where you can just call `{this.renderValue}`

Comment: @Nathan We shouldn't as a community spread a rule of "Avoid creating functions in the render method", there is no measurable evidence that it has a huge impact on the performance, I suggest reading this article: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578